# DialogFragment : EditText keyboard covers whole screen in landscape mode

Tags: android, dialog, dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` with two input fields and two buttons. In `portrait mode` everything is fine, but in `landscape mode` when an input field is focused the whole Dialog disappears so the buttons are not there. Screen is then covered by a keyboard and a "next" buttons [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed8F7.png) (where does it come from ?). What can I do to prevent ? Tried setting `android:windowSoftInputMode` but no difference

Comment: You can prevent landscape mode.

Comment: This is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use different layouts:

```
res/layout [Portrait Mode; default]
 main.xml
res/layout-land [Landscape Mode]
 main.xml
```

Comment: But how different ? DialogFragment gets hidden even if I have a single EditText in landscape layout